# Casio fx-100AU COS calculation error

Tags: trigonometry, calculator

I am calculating the following on my Casio fx-100AU:

`7.5cos((2pi/365)*24)+21.5` -> `28.99980502`, which is incorrect it should be `28.368982162`

I narrowed down the error to the cos calculation...

`2pi/365 * 24 = 0.4131409517`, the cos result for `0.4131409517` on my calculator is `0.9999740032`, where as an online calculator is `0.91586428826`.

My question is this normal for a calculation to be so far out for this type of calculation?

Comment: The value of cosine given by the online calculator is incorrect **if you really mean $365$ there**.

Comment: Is your angle in degrees or radians? That's the primary issue here, not how the calculator works.

Comment: The Casio result is the correct result for $0.4131409517$ degrees. If you want it to accept an angle in radians there is probably a "radians" mode you can switch to.

Comment: Oh awesome Sean and David!  Switching to Radians is correct.  Really appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** Your calculator uses incorrect angle unit, see this part of user's guide: [users guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi25O.png)

**Solution**: Press the [MODE] key and then select [1] for degrees or [2] for radians.

This can be confirmed with below calculation with Pari/GP:

```
Reading GPRC: /etc/gprc
GPRC Done.

                  GP/PARI CALCULATOR Version 2.13.1 (released)
          amd64 running linux (x86-64/GMP-6.2.1 kernel) 64-bit version
      compiled: Jan 25 2021, gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
                            threading engine: pthread
                 (readline v8.1 enabled, extended help enabled)

                     Copyright (C) 2000-2020 The PARI Group

PARI/GP is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and comes
WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY WHATSOEVER.

Type ? for help, \q to quit.
Type ?17 for how to get moral (and possibly technical) support.

parisize = 8000000, primelimit = 500000
? cos(0.4131409517)
%1 = 0.91586428826927817341306651006376638197

? cos(0.4131409517*Pi/180)
%2 = 0.99997400323256593026613148347067028673
```